# How do I open a exe in a parent folder?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How do I open a exe in a parent folder?

An example would be

Debug\Folder1\Folder2

There is an exe in folder2 and folder1

I want it so when I click button with the exe in folder2 it opens up a exe in folder1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void OpenEXE_BtnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var currentFolder = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var parentFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(currentFolder);
        var exeFile = Path.Combine(parentFolder, "{FileName}");
        try
        {
            using (Process myProcess = new Process())
            {
                myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = exeFile;
                myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                myProcess.Start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Some thing happend when trying run background backup!!" + Environment.NewLine + ex.Message,
                "Running Background Backup", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
}
```